# Why is Ubuntu 16.04 very slow on my laptop?

Tags: unity, ram

[image: Output of free -h]

I have a Lenovo ideapad 110 with AMD E1-7010 and 4 Gigabytes of RAM. The whole sytem is very slow. When I open Google Chrome it takes a lot to respond or when I double click to make it full screen while watching videos on YouTube takes a lot ot time to change to full screen

Output of `free -h`

```
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           3.3G        1.6G        101M         51M        1.6G        1.3G
Swap:          3.8G          0B        3.8G
```

Edit : I have installed windows 10 and the system is very smooth. So can anyone tell me what the problem with Ubuntu is? Is Ubuntu not compatible with SOC processors?

Comment: Please run `free -h` and post the output into your question!

Comment: I put image link up in the post

Comment: Please copy and past the out put no image text.

Comment: total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           3.3G        1.6G        101M         51M        1.6G        1.3G
Swap:          3.8G          0B        3.8G

Comment: Please use appropriate formatting when posting. I have fixed the formatting a bit. :)

Comment: In the light of [RoVo’s answer](/a/944535/175814) this question is a possible duplicate of [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](/q/206407/175814)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not related to RAM. You have almost half of the RAM available and the system is not swapping.

But your CPU is pretty slow (Dual Core 1.5GHz)

> the SoC is only suited for very basic tasks like web surfing (not many tabs), word processing and video playback. ([via](https://www.notebookcheck.net/AMD-E-Series-E1-7010-Notebook-Processor.145046.0.html))

Recommended System requirements for Ubuntu 16.04:

> 2GHz dual core processor or better

Try to use a more lightweight desktop like [LXDE](http://lxde.org/).

```
sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop
```

---

See some closely related questions:

- [How to improve Ubuntu performance on netbook](https://askubuntu.com/a/207674/631600)
- [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](https://askubuntu.com/q/206407/175814)

Comment: is the performance will be the same if i installed windows 10 or it will be better ? because i can't stand horrible performance now .

Comment: this is a different question but maybe not good to ask at askubuntu  ;-). I have no idea ...

Comment: @GeorgeGhaleb A system that can run W10 would be able to run Ubuntu 16.04. Ubuntu's min. specs have always been lower than those of Windows when taking their release date into account.

Comment: I have installed windows 10 and the system is very smooth .. so can anyone tell me what is the problem with Ubuntu ? is Ubuntu not compatible with SOC processors ?